# Show that $\sigma_\bar Y^2$ , the variance of the sample mean, $\bar Y$ , is given by $\sigma_\bar Y^2 = \frac {N-n}{N-1}\frac {\sigma^2}{n}$

Tags: statistics, covariance, means, variance

This is really frustrating me,

So I know that $\bar Y$ =$ \frac {1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$

And I have that $Cov(Y_i, Y_j) = \frac {-\sigma^2}{(N-1)}$

I know that population mean $\mu = \frac {1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_i$
and population variance $\frac {\sum_{i=1}^N (x_i-\mu)^2}{N}$

But from this point I am clueless

Comment: Sampling without replacement from a finite population?

Answer (score 1):

$Var(\overline{Y})=\dfrac{1}{n^2}Var(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i)=\dfrac{1}{n^2}[\sum_{i=1}^n Var(Y_i)+\sum_{i\neq j}Cov(Y_i,Y_j)]$

Can you take up from here?

Comment: I'll have an attempt from here. I didn't even know that was what you had to do! Thanks, I'll let you know how I get on

Comment: Hey man, I still couldn't do this. I haven't learnt about covariance couples in class so this really confuses me

Comment: Your notation only has $n$. How do you propose to produce a result containing $N$ and $n$?

Comment: $Cov(Y_i,Y_j)=-\sigma^2/(N-1)$ given.Also $\sigma^2=Var(Y_i)$ for each $i$. Put these into the above expression.