# What are the variances of sample means for simple random samples drawn with and without replacement from a normal population?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, variance

What are the variances of sample means for simple random samples drawn with and without replacement from a normal population?

There are other answers on Stack like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/751547/1092056) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2300332/1092056) where this is solved, but they do not explain how it is done. First of all, how do I pick a sample from a normal distribution and calculate its mean?

Comment: How do you define sampling *with replacement* from a normal population? I am unsure you can unless the population is not really normal

Comment: @Snoop If I knew, I wouldn't be asking! (The value given is $\sigma^2/n$ for this, if that helps. $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of the normal distribution.)

Comment: The concept of _replacement_ does not make sense in a continuous distribution, where the probability of drawing any specific value is equal to $0$. The density of a normal distribution with finitely many individual points removed is exactly the same as a regular normal density with the same mean and variance.